# SiriKit intent definition file is not creating

Tags: sirikit, xcode10

I have been installed xCode Version 10.0 beta 5 (10L221o) and wants to develop on Siri shortcut application. I want to create SiriKit intent Definition file. But it is not creating. When I clicks on create, it does happen something. Is that feature is not available in this version or some other possible problems.